# Weak homotopy equivalence and Cech cohomology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

If two topological spaces are weak homotopy equivalent to each other, are their Cech cohomology groups the same?

Comment: The obvious and well known (I am sure :-) answer is NO  (regardless of is or are :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$T = \left\{  \left( x, \sin \frac{1}{x}  \right ) :  x \in (0,1] \right\} \cup \{(0,y)\mid y\in[-1,1]\}$$

This has trivial homotopy groups in degrees $\ge1$ but according to Wikipedia nontrivial Čech cohomology in degree 1.

Answer (score 4):

To give a more enlightening answer to the question:

Cech cohomology is *not* the same as singular cohomology. However it *is* on CW-complexes. But there is CW approximation for topological spaces and singular cohomology is a weak homotopy invariant, so Cech cohomology can't be.